# C - Run program with parameters such as ./prog -p 8888

Tags: c, parameters

So I'm doing communication between server and client in C. I'm having issues with searching for it on the web how to do the following.

```
./server -p 1234
./client -p 1234 -h asdffdsasdf
```

Can someone describe the basics of doing it inside the project or is it included in the Makefile??(Using Putty terminal).

Or show me a website where it is explained very well, because I dont know what to google for this.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking. But the answer may be `./server -p 1234 & ./client -p 1234 -h asdffdsasdf` which runs them concurrently. Unless windows.

Comment: No I'm asking about what I need to do so I can run it with parameters, how do I create that..

Now I can open 2x putties and do
./server in one of them and then
./client in the other..

And get a response of what I want. But at the moment there is a fixed port number.

Somehow I must incorperate it so that I will do ./server -p XXXX
So my server runs on port XXXX,

To connect to it I must do the same for client
./client -p XXXX

So I get the correct response back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use program startup arguments; see [Standard 5.1.2.2.1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.1).

For example

```
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc >= 2) {
        if (strcmp(argv[1], "-p") == 0) /* -p detected */;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

*<sup>TLDR: just read the title</sup>*

Comment: This will also work with multiple parameters? even if I would have a list of 5 different ones?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it works with how many parameters you need. Just check `argc` before accessing `argv`.